# Game streaming is turned off on your Xbox One message appears even though streaming is enabled

Tags: xbox-one, streaming, windows-10

I am attempting to stream games from my Xbox One to my Windows 10 PC.  I am running across the odd error of being able to connect to the Xbox in the Windows 10 Xbox app but when I try to stream a game I get the following error

> Game streaming is turned off on your Xbox One. To turn it back on, go
>   to your console and open Settings > Preferences

However when I go to my Xbox Game Streaming is enabled. I have the following settings enabled under Settings > Preferences

- Allow Play To streaming
- Allow broadcast and game captures
- Allow game streaming to other devices
- From any SmartGlass device

Also when I do the stream test it returns a red X for each quality setting. This makes me think there is some kind of network problem. Currently both my Xbox and my Windows 10 PC are on a 5 ghz wireless network and are under 10 ft from the router. I also tried having the Xbox wired to the router and the Windows 10 PC on the 5 ghz wireless network but I still have the same problem. Due to the layout of my apartment it it would not be easy to connect my PC to the wired network but could be possible.

What else do I need to do to be able to stream Xbox One games to my PC?

Comment: 3 questions:   What video card does your PC have?  Is your PC firewall on/off?  Have you hard reset your xbox one?

Comment: Video Card: AMD Radeon R9 M295X Firewall: On Hard Rest: No will give these a try

Comment: Turning off my firewall and performing a hard reset doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I have the same problem. I have 2 laptops, one with Nvidia, one with the beta app one with the other, both have the media pack installed. On both the same message. So indeed, I'm thinking it must be network/

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows 10 are you running?  If it is Windows 10 N or KN, the OS doesn't have some multimedia components (specifically, "Media Feature Pack") installed by default, you have to install them separately.  Windows unhelpfully doesn't prompt you with the real reason streaming isn't working.

Get the installer for Media Feature Pack from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=48231).

Source: [Xbox Forums](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_on_windows_support/f/5413/t/2046325.aspx).

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Pro N 64 Bit, I downloaded the media feature pack and it said I already had it installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Even 2 laptops, one with Nvidia one with  Intel gfx, both Windows 10. Both Nogo. All settings on xbox one correct. Tried a gazillion options. nogo.